# CSS in IE: Background image position is not updated on ajax update

Tags: css, ajax, internet-explorer-7, background-image

I have 2 DIVs - when the upper DIV gets replaced by a higher DIV (using AJAX), the *content* of the lower DIV gets pushed down just like it should, but not the (repeated) *background image*:

```
background: url("../images/background.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 #E6E6E6;
```

This only happens in IE (7, to be precise).

What could be the problem here?

Thanks for any help with this!

Tom

Comment: Please post a working example, save it and post the URL (go to: http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Can you post an example showing you issue on jsfiddle?  Or if you have a code sample you can post mainly looking for the html, css, and parts of the js that interact with these divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is/was related to the use of the .htc solution (rounded corners, cross-browser: http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/list).

So no solid rounded corners in IE <= 7 without images.